# How can I modify a comparator behavior on sap commerce?

Tags: comparator, sap-commerce-cloud

I'm trying to override the "EQUALS" or "GREATER" comparator in Sap commerce cloud (hybris), and I was wondering which is the correct way to do it. I want to modify this field as when comparing the equals with a date, it does not take into account the hour of the date. I would like to override the comparator to have the hour into account.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

For equals, there exists an out of the box [configuration](https://help.sap.com/viewer/5c9ea0c629214e42b727bf08800d8dfa/2011/en-US/8b50ccf3866910149e1c9ebdd47f12be.html#loio257c9eb8a3f64b76a33785a35e3936ef__section_filtering_date) you can use to ignore the time aspect. `equalsComparesExactDate`

```
<advanced-search:field name="date">
    <advanced-search:editor-parameter>
        <advanced-search:name>equalsComparesExactDate</advanced-search:name>
        <advanced-search:value>false</advanced-search:value>
    </advanced-search:editor-parameter>
</advanced-search:field>
```

According to the documentation, there is also `comparesExactDate`, for the other operators to ignore the time component

```
<advanced-search:editor-parameter>
    <advanced-search:name>comparesExactDate</advanced-search:name>
    <advanced-search:value>false</advanced-search:value>
</advanced-search:editor-parameter>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
<advanced-search:field name="date" selected="true">
    <advanced-search:editor-parameter>
        <advanced-search:name>comparesExactDate</advanced-search:name>
        <advanced-search:value>true</advanced-search:value>
    </advanced-search:editor-parameter>
    <advanced-search:editor-parameter>
        <advanced-search:name>equalsComparesExactDate</advanced-search:name>
        <advanced-search:value>false</advanced-search:value>
    </advanced-search:editor-parameter>                   
</advanced-search:field>
```